# std::multimap error when calling end()

Tags: c++, null, iterator, multimap

How can I check if an element of a multimap exists?
With this code:

```
typedef std::multimap<std::string, std::string> TagVal;
TagVal tv;
//... add values to tv ...
TagVal::const_iterator it = tv.find("abc");
if(it == TagVal::end())    // <--- ERROR
    cerr << "Error";
```

I get the following compile time error:

> error: cannot call member function 'std::multimap<...>::iterator std::multimap<...>::end() ...
>   without object.

Platform: Linux, GCC 4.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `end` is not a static method, it has to be called on the object you got the iterator from:

```
if(it == tv.end())
    cerr << "Error";
```

Answer (score 1):

since you have initialised `tv` as

`TagVal tv;`

you have to call end() function of multimap class as:

`it == tv.end()`

as the end() is called on that object and it is not a static method.